# При html {width: 100%; height: 100%} блок html не разворачивается на всю высоту страницы

Tags: html, css

При `html {width: 100%; height: 100%}` блок `html` не разворачивается на всю высоту страницы. И от `width: 760px` появляется боковой отступ и горизонтальный `scroll`. Не могу найти косяк. Прошу помощи. Лежит на сервере [cleaning.transkribator](http://cleaning.transkribator.ru)

Comment: body тоже нужно задавать высоту height: 100%

Answer (score 1):

И не развернётся. Надо так:

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;   /* высота всем нужна */
  margin: 0;      /* это для body */
}

main {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, blue, red);
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: решил добраться до сути и начал раскладывать все сначала. Все задано, как подсказали и html и body все равно не раскрывается вот здесь пример: http://cleaning.transkribator.ru/index2.html

Comment: удивительно - убрал html {height:100%} - все сразу стало ровно и html растянулся в высоту на 100%